# redis-7.0.5.tar.gz SHA256 hash

Tags: redis, download, sha256, verify

The redis tarball hashes page at this URL:  https://github.com/redis/redis-hashes/ lists the following SHA-256 hash for redis-7.0.5.tar.gz

hash redis-7.0.5.tar.gz sha256 67054cc37b58c125df93bd78000261ec0ef4436a26b40f38262c780e56315cc3

How is this hash generated/on what platform?

After downloading the gz file, tried matching the hash and the hashes do not match.

Tried on Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server release 7.9 (Maipo)

Tried sha256sum with and without -b option

$ sha256sum redis-7.0.5.tar.gz
40827fcaf188456ad9b3be8e27a4f403c43672b6bb6201192dc15756af6f1eae  redis-7.0.5.tar.gz

$ sha256sum -b redis-7.0.5.tar.gz
40827fcaf188456ad9b3be8e27a4f403c43672b6bb6201192dc15756af6f1eae *redis-7.0.5.tar.gz

Tried python hashlib.sha256() (reading file in "rb" mode)
$ python a.py
40827fcaf188456ad9b3be8e27a4f403c43672b6bb6201192dc15756af6f1eae

Tried Windows 10
certutil -hashfile redis-7.0.5.tar.gz SHA256
SHA256 hash of redis-7.0.5.tar.gz:
40827fcaf188456ad9b3be8e27a4f403c43672b6bb6201192dc15756af6f1eae

How did the redis site get 67054cc37b58c125df93bd78000261ec0ef4436a26b40f38262c780e56315cc3 ?

What am i missing....

Answer (score 0):

Your downloaded file is corrupted. Just delete the file and download again.

I have just tested in my PC. My OS is Debian and I have downloaded by Firefox web browser.

```
$ sha256sum redis-7.0.5.tar.gz 
67054cc37b58c125df93bd78000261ec0ef4436a26b40f38262c780e56315cc3  redis-7.0.5.tar.gz
```

Comment: thanks for your time & effort.
The contents of the gz file we got look ok. 
I was able to gunzip, untar, do a "make", "make test" and was able to launch redis-server and redis-cli and do a PING-PONG test successfully.